# Castle Windsor - Register component for eventhandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I am new to IoC and especially Castle Windsor. I'm trying to register component for eventpublisher which look like this:

```
  container.Register(Component.For<IEventPublisher>().ImplementedBy<EventPublisher>());
```

I'm sure that the container register code above is correct, but I get another error message which says:

> Can't create component 'Network.Infrastructure.Event.EventPublisher' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.'Network.Infrastructure.Event.EventPublisher' is waiting for the following dependencies:- Service 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[Network.Infrastructure.Event.IEventListener, Network.Infrastructure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' which was not registered.

I have also tried to register IEventListener, but with no luck.

ArticleService.cs

```
   public class ArticleService : IArticleService
{
    private readonly IArticleRepository _articleRpRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    **Declaring the field for IEventPublisher**
    private readonly IEventPublisher _eventPublisher;


    public ArticleService(IArticleRepository articleRpRepository, IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IEventPublisher eventListener)
    {
        _articleRpRepository = articleRpRepository;
        _eventPublisher = eventListener;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public Article CreateArticle(Article article)
    {
            **Using the publish from eventpublish class** 
            _eventPublisher.Publish(new MyEvent { Message = "Something is done" });

            article.Created = DateTime.Now;
            _articleRpRepository.Add(article);
            SaveChanges();

            return article;
        }

    }
```

EventPublisher.cs

```
  public class EventPublisher : IEventPublisher
    {

   private readonly IEnumerable<IEventListener> _listeners;

   public EventPublisher(IEnumerable<IEventListener> listeners)
    {
        _listeners = listeners;
    }

    public void Publish<TPayload>(TPayload payload) where TPayload : class
    {
        var handlersForPayload = _listeners.OfType<IEventListener<TPayload();
        foreach (var handler in handlersForPayload)
        {
            handler.Handle(payload);
        }
    }
}
```

IEventListener.cs

```
public interface IEventListener
 {}

public interface IEventListener<in TPayload> : IEventListener where TPayload : class
{

    void Handle(TPayload payload);
}
```

Comment: Windsor is telling you that it can't resolve `IEnumerbable<IEventListener>` that it needs to create an instance of `EventPublisher`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add CollectionResolver to the container and than register your listeners.

```
container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));
```

More info about resolvers here:

https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md